# Is this an OK test to see if a variable is set

Tags: php, if-statement

Yesterday, I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285618/is-null-not-working-as-expected/3285948#3285948) to a question that included several (unknown to me at the time) very bad code examples.  Since then, I've been looking at my fundamental knowledge of PHP that allowed me to think that such code is possible.  This brings me to a question that I can't seem to find an answer to:

If I want to check for whether or not a variable has anything set, is it a valid practice to *not* use `isset()` or another helper function?  here's a "for instance":

```
if($not_set){
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Rather than...

```
if(isset($not_set)){
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

From the name of the variable, you can see that this variable is not set.  Therefore the conditional would be false and the `else` portion would run.  Up until now I have been using this practice, but after the posts yesterday, I now have an inkling that this is wrong.

Here's why I thought that it would be an ok practice to leave out the `isset()` function above.  From PHP manual:

> The if construct is one of the most
> important features of many languages,
> PHP included. It allows for
> conditional execution of code
> fragments. PHP features an if
> structure that is similar to that of
> C:
>
> if (expr)   statement
>
> As described in the section about
> expressions, expression is evaluated
> to its Boolean value. If expression
> evaluates to TRUE, PHP will execute
> statement, and if it evaluates to
> FALSE - it'll ignore it. More
> information about what values evaluate
> to FALSE can be found in the
> 'Converting to boolean' section.

And from the 'Converting to boolean section':

> When converting to boolean
> , the following values are considered
> FALSE:
>
> ...
> * the special type NULL (including unset variables)

Why would the manual go out of its way to state that unset variables are included if this is a bad practice?  If it's unset, it gets converted to NULL and therefore is evaluated properly by the conditional.  Using `isset()` will find the same result, but will take extra cycles to do so.

Have I been wrong this whole time, and if so, why?  (And just how bad it is, maybe?)

Comment: Well, your approach *will* catch unset variables, but it will also catch other variables which *are* set. So it's not really a test for variables being set

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly

Comment: Hey deceze!  Thanks for everything yesterday - huge leap in my PHP understanding (as you can see).  I didn't see that one when I was searching, but that's basically the same thing I was thinking.

Comment: I just want to reiterate one of my comments in the thread linked to above: `isset` helps to clarify your code and aid debugging: `if (isset($var))` means "this variable is optional and may be absent", and the rest of your code needs to treat it as such. `if ($var)` just means "if true". If PHP throws a warning for the latter one, you know your code is screwed somewhere. And you always need to program with error reporting on full blast for this reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will run in to problems if your variable is set, but evaluates to FALSE, like the following:

- the boolean **FALSE** itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the
       string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member
       variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including
       unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty
       tags

Taken from the PHP manual.

Basically, using isset() is showing that you are explicitly checking if a variable exists and is not NULL, while the structure of your if statement only checks if the variable is true. It is more clear and less error-prone.

Comment: `isset` checks if a variable **exists** (*is set*), and is not `null`. The *is set* part is a lot more important than the *not `null`* part.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Edited to make add that in.

Answer (score 11):

If the variable is not set you get a `Notice`. If you use `isset()` you don't get a notice. So from an error reporting point of view, using `isset()` is better :)

Example:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);   
if($a) {
   echo 'foo';
}
```

gives

```
Notice: Undefined variable: a in /Users/kling/test on line 5
```

whereas

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($a)) {
   echo 'foo';
}
```

does not output anything.

---

The bottom line: If code quality is important to you, use `isset()`.

Comment: From *error reporting* point of view, using isset is worse. Obviously, when you are trying to access a variable that doesn't exist, it's an error. And isset effectively works as an error suppression operator. The bottom line: If code quality is important to you, use isset() with caution, basically with only outside variables you have no control for.

Answer (score 7):

It's *okay* but not good practice to use `if` to check for a set variable. Two reasons off the top of my head:

1. Using `isset` makes the intent clear - that you're checking whether the variable is set, and not instead checking whether a condition is true.
2. `if ($not_set)` will evaluate to false when `$not_set` is actually set but is equal to boolean `false`.

Answer (score 4):

It is a common practise, but is not good -- you should always use `isset`!

If your `$not_set` is set, and is a bool with the value `false`, your "test" will fail!

Answer (score 1):

`isset` works as a guard preventing you from using variables that do not actually exist.
`if (isset($foo))` and `if ($foo)` do not mean the same thing. `isset` just tells you if the variable actually exists and if it's okay to use it, it does not evaluate the value of the variable itself`*`.

Hence, you should usually use one of these two patterns:

If the variable is sure to exist and you just want to check its value:

```
if ($foo == 'bar')
```

If the variable may or may not exist, and you want to check its value:

```
if (isset($foo) && $foo == 'bar')
```

If you're just interested that a variable *is set* and evaluates to `true`, i.e. `if ($foo)`, you can use `empty`:

```
if (isset($foo) && $foo)
// is the same as
if (!empty($foo))
```

---

`*` it does check for `null`, where `null` is as good as not being set at all